# How do I reduce the capacity of a solar water heater tank

Tags: water, heater

I have a solar water heater system that takes a lot of sun hours to warm up and that cools down too fast.  I live in Puerto Rico, so the outside air temps and sun hours are not the problem.  After 10 years, I believe the problem is that the water tank is too big (120 gals) for the number of sun tubes.
The only opening of the tank is approximately 2 inches wide, to screw in the electric heating element.  Is there any material I can induce into the tank, that would expand (like a balloon) so as to reduce the capacity?

Comment: Pictures would be good.  Also a short explanation of the design of the system and how it works.

Comment: If it cools too quickly, reducing the water volume will exacerbate that. You can't have it both ways without insulation.

Comment: sounds more like you need better insulation for the tank

Comment: How many gallons per minute is your circulating pump rated for? You could parallel that with another pump to increase flow rate during peak sun hours.

Comment: The system has a number of glass tubes that heat the water in sun light.  There is no pump, but the heated water moves up to the tank.  I have tried insulation around the tank with little improvement.  The problem is that the water cools after one day without sun, whereas other systems seem to keep warm for several days.

Comment: Have you verified that the problem is actually that it cools too fast rather than isn't heating to the temperature you expect?  Has it always performed the same and you just reached a conclusion as to why, or is the performance deteriorating?  A day is a long time to expect it to retain heat, even with typical insulation.  What happens to the water in the tubes on days without sun (do the tubes continue to feed water or does it stop feed through the tubes)?